# Efficient way to validate state and zip code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, validation

I'm looking for a easy way to validate state and zip code (U.S Only). Obviously there are many ways that this can be done. I have zip code:

```
- (BOOL)validateZipCode
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    NSString *zipcodeExpression = @"^[0-9]{5}(-/d{4})?$"; //U.S Zip ONLY!!!
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:zipcodeExpression options:0 error:NULL];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:ZipCodeTextField.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [ZipCodeTextField.text length])];
    if (match)
    {
       returnValue = true;
    }
   return returnValue;
 }
```

Would it be common to just have a list of all the states and abbreviations and just compare the user input to check for a match? This just seems like a lot.

I guess I'm looking for alternatives. I also heard of some frameworks that when a user inputs a zip code, the city and state are then auto generated. Does anyone know of any alternatives like this?

Comment: To my knowledge, the first 3 digits of the zip code identifies the state.  So a table of 1000 entries should be able to verify that zip code matches state.  Verifying that the low 2 digits are valid would require something more complex, and is probably best left to a network service or a database, though you could perhaps use a bit vector or some such.

Comment: See @rmaddy answer vis-a-vis the top 3 digits, they aren't guaranteed to cover only a single state.  Zip code verification is a non-trivial process and can be highly annoying to customers if done wrong.   Accurate databases are expensive and large.   If you're doing this on-device, I'd suggest verifying the format, but if you don't want to annoy some customer in a border condition, stay away from the numeric verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple plist file in your app preloaded with the state names and abbreviations is trivial enough. Your regular expression will validate that a string represents a valid zip code.

If you need to actually verify that the zip code and the state match, that will take a lot more data.

A quick google search should reveal some web services you may be able to use to get a state from a zip code. Zip codes change (at least new ones added) on occasion. You may be able to provide a state/zip code database file in your app. But you will need a way to update the database once in a while without needing to submit an update of your app.

Update: A quick look at the [Wikipedia Zip Code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code) reveals that some zip codes span more than one state.